# Calling Objective-C alternate implementations of Foundation classes from Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I’m working with the AVCaptureDeviceInput class, part of the AVFoundation in Swift.  The iniitializer is throwing an exception, and I’d like to find out the cause of the exception.  There is supposed to be a NSError object that gives the info.  The API Reference documentation of the Swift call is:

```
Declaration
init(device: AVCaptureDevice!) throws
Parameters
device
The device from which to capture input.
outError
If an error occurs during initialization, upon return contains an NSError object describing the problem.
```

XCode isn’t allowing me to add a second argument to my call to `AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device!)`.  It appears to me that the documentation is wrong about having an outError parameter.

The API Reference also has an Objective-C definition as follows:

```
Declaration
- (instancetype)initWithDevice:(AVCaptureDevice *)device 
                     error:(NSError **)outError;
Parameters
device
The device from which to capture input.
outError
If an error occurs during initialization, upon return contains an NSError object     describing the problem.
Return Value
An input initialized to use device.
```

I've seen example code online that returns the NSError, but it's in Swift 2.  Is there a way I can get that in Swift 3?

Answer (score 2):

> It appears to me that the documentation is wrong about having an outError parameter

Well, it isn't wrong. See the `throws` marking? That's how you get the error parameter in Swift. You have to call this initializer with a `try`. If you embed this in a `do`, you get the error in the `catch`:

```
do {
    let d = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device:aDevice)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Please note, however, that this won't help you unless the framework really *is* failing in good order and passing an NSError to you. If you are *crashing* (for example, because you are trying to unwrap `nil` or something similar), you'll still just crash.

Comment: And see my online book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_throwing_and_catching_errors The discussion of how this corresponds to the Objective-C `error:(NSError **)outError` construct is towards the end of that section.